# Troubleshooting Rails / Puma locking up when running locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

I've been having an issue where my local Rails / Puma server will lock up after running for a while. I suspect this may have to with the log data, but am honestly not even sure where to begin troubleshooting this.

What happens is that the server will lock up and is unresponsive, no log messages in console etc. The fix being to restart the local server. The odd thing is that when I run the command to stop the server (`control + c`) a bunch of normal log messages will be printed to the console before it shuts down. Additionally, I've noticed that if I periodically manually clear the console log (`command + k`) this doesn't happen. This leads me to believe that it may have something todo with a log file size limit.

I have not noticed this issue in any of the staging or production environments, only localhost.

Server is started with a `Procfile` using `foreman` with `foreman start -f Procfile.dev`

I'm wondering if this may be a `STDOUT` issue and not specifically related to Rails / Puma, but any advice in trying to track this down would be appreciated!

**Current Local Setup (although this has been a consistent issue with pervious versions as well)**

- macOS 13.6.1
- using `bash` (not `zsh`)
- Rails 7.0.8
- Ruby 2.7.8
- Puma 4.3.12
- Sidekiq 6.5.12
- foreman 0.87.2

**config/environments/development.rb**

```
require "active_support/core_ext/integer/time"

require "dotenv"
Dotenv.load

Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = false
  config.eager_load = false
  config.consider_all_requests_local = true
  config.server_timing = true

  if Rails.root.join("tmp/caching-dev.txt").exist?
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
    config.action_controller.enable_fragment_cache_logging = true

    config.cache_store = :memory_store
    config.public_file_server.headers = {
      "Cache-Control" => "public, max-age=#{2.days.to_i}"
    }
  else
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
    config.cache_store = :null_store
  end

  config.active_storage.service = :local
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = ActiveModel::Type::Boolean.new.cast(ENV.fetch('RAILS_MAILER_DELIVERY_ERRORS') { true })
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
  config.active_support.disallowed_deprecation = :raise
  config.active_support.disallowed_deprecation_warnings = []
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load
  config.active_record.verbose_query_logs = true
  config.assets.quiet = true
  config.assets.debug = true
  config.assets.quiet = true
  config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker

  config.action_cable.mount_path  = ":#{ ENV.fetch('DEFAULT_PORT') { 5000 } }/cable"
  config.action_cable.url         = "wss://#{ ENV.fetch('HOST') { 'localhost' } }:#{ ENV.fetch('DEFAULT_PORT') { 5000 } }/cable"
  config.web_socket_server_url    = "wss://#{ ENV.fetch('HOST') { 'localhost' } }:#{ ENV.fetch('DEFAULT_PORT') { 5000 } }/cable"

  config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [/http:\/\/#{ENV['HOST']}*/, /https:\/\/#{ENV['HOST']}*/]

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
    protocol: ENV.fetch('PROTOCOL') { 'https' },
    host: ENV.fetch('HOST') { 'localhost' },
    port: ENV.fetch('DEFAULT_PORT') { 3000 }
  }

  config.logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
  config.log_level = (ENV.fetch('RAILS_LOG_LEVEL') { 'debug' }).to_sym

  config.sass.inline_source_maps = true
  config.assets.unknown_asset_fallback = true
  config.force_ssl = true
  config.assets.prefix = '/dev-assets'
  config.action_dispatch.cookies_same_site_protection = :strict

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = ENV.fetch('MAIL_DELIVERY_METHOD') { 'letter_opener' }.to_sym
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
end
```

**config/puma/development.rb**

```
require "dotenv"
Dotenv.load

max_threads_count = ENV.fetch('RAILS_MAX_THREADS') { 5 }
min_threads_count = ENV.fetch('RAILS_MIN_THREADS') { max_threads_count }
threads min_threads_count, max_threads_count

port ENV.fetch('DEFAULT_PORT') { 3000 }
environment ENV.fetch('RAILS_ENV') { 'development' }
workers ENV.fetch('WEB_CONCURRENCY') { 5 }

preload_app!

before_fork do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.disconnect! if defined?(ActiveRecord)
end

on_worker_boot do
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection if defined?(ActiveRecord)
end

if ENV.fetch('HOST') { 'localhost' } === 'localhost'
  ssl_key = "#{File.join('config', 'certs', 'localhost', 'localhost.key')}"
  ssl_crt = "#{File.join('config', 'certs', 'localhost', 'localhost.crt')}"
end

host = ENV.fetch('HOST') { 'localhost' }
port = ENV.fetch('SSL_PORT') { ENV.fetch('DEFAULT_PORT') { 3000 } }

ssl_bind host, port, {
  key: ssl_key,
  cert: ssl_crt,
  verify_mode: 'none'
}
```

**Procfile.dev**

```
web: RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec puma
webpacker: ./bin/webpack-dev-server
redis: redis-server
worker1: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
worker2: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
worker3: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
worker4: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
worker5: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
worker6: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
worker7: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
worker8: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
```

Comment: How long does it take before it stops responding?

Comment: @MikeSzyndel it depends, some times 10-20min, sometimes hours. The only thing that seems consistent is that it seems to correlate with the amount of logs being sent to the console